How to pass a second array through my functions without altering the first array
I'm trying to create a second game mode in a js quiz. I have one game mode running as expected and another set of questions in another array waiting to be used. However, I'm very new to js and struggling how to pass the second array through all my code without altering the first set of data.
I've tried an if statement that uses the 2nd array but then the rest of the functions stop working. I've tried passing the array through my createQuestion function but it creates errors in the console. Such as
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '1')
    at createQuestion (script.js:184:35)
    at HTMLButtonElement.nextQuestion (script.js:236:5)

The 2nd array I would like to pass through looks like this
let quizData2 = [
    {
        question: "assets/images/year/Brazil98-00.avif",
        answers: ["1997", "1999", "2002", "1995"],
        correct: "1999",
    },
    {
        question: "assets/images/year/Denmark-92.webp",
        answers: ["1991", "1990", "1995", "1992"],
        correct: "1992",
    },

When the start guess shirt year function is called I would like the 2nd arrays data set to be used.
document.getElementById('guess-shirt-start-btn').addEventListener('click', startGuessShirtTeam);
document.getElementById('guess-year-start-btn').addEventListener('click', startGuessShirtYear);

// function to start the Guess the Shirt type game
function startGuessShirtTeam () {
    document.getElementById('game-choices-container').classList.add('hidden');
    document.getElementById('question-container').classList.remove('hidden');
    gameMode = 'shirt-quiz'
    modeOfGame(); 
    console.log(gameMode)
    createQuestion(quizData1);
    displayNumberOfQuestions();
};

function startGuessShirtYear () {
    document.getElementById('game-choices-container').classList.add('hidden');
    document.getElementById('question-container').classList.remove('hidden');
    gameMode = 'shirt-year'
    modeOfGame();
    console.log(gameMode)
    createQuestion(quizData2)
    displayNumberOfQuestions();
}

I can get the first question from both arrays displaying but my subsequent check answer and next question functions stop working.
function createQuestion (questionArray) {
    displayQuestionTitle();

    shirtImage.src = questionArray[questionNumber].question;
    
    questionArray[questionNumber].answers.forEach((o) => {
        document.getElementById('answer-button-1').innerText = questionArray[questionNumber].answers[0]
        document.getElementById('answer-button-2').innerText = questionArray[questionNumber].answers[1]
        document.getElementById('answer-button-3').innerText = questionArray[questionNumber].answers[2]
        document.getElementById('answer-button-4').innerText = questionArray[questionNumber].answers[3]
    });
    document.getElementById('answer-button-1').addEventListener('click', checkAnswer);
    document.getElementById('answer-button-2').addEventListener('click', checkAnswer);
    document.getElementById('answer-button-3').addEventListener('click', checkAnswer);
    document.getElementById('answer-button-4').addEventListener('click', checkAnswer);
};

My next question function
function nextQuestion () {
    let allAnswers = document.querySelectorAll('.answer-btns');
    allAnswers.forEach((o) => {
        o.classList.remove('disabled')
    });
    if (questionNumber >= maxQuestions - 1) {
        displayQuizResult();
        return;
    }
    questionNumber++;
    clearCorrectAnswer();
    clearQuestionTitle();
    createQuestion();
    clearAnswers();
    showCurrentQuestionNumber();
}

Check answer function
function checkAnswer (e) {
    let userAnswer = e.target.textContent;
    if (userAnswer === questionArray[questionNumber].correct) {
        userScore++;
        finalScore++;
        e.target.classList.add("correct");
        showUserScore();
    } else {
        e.target.classList.add("incorrect");
        let correct = document.getElementById('correct-answer');
        let correctAnswer = document.createTextNode(`Sorry that's incorrect, the answer is ${questionArray[questionNumber].correct}`);

    correct.appendChild(correctAnswer);
    }

    let allAnswers = document.querySelectorAll('.answer-btns');
    allAnswers.forEach((o) => {
        o.classList.add('disabled')
    });
};


What is the first array?

questionArray[questionNumber].answers.forEach((o) => why doesn't the function use o? You're filling in all the answers each time through the loop.

Every time you call createQuestion() you add event listeners to the answer buttons, but you never remove the listeners from the previous question. You should just do this once when the program starts, not every time you change questions.

The basic problem is that checkAnswer() doesn't know which is the current set of quiz data? You could use a global variable to refer to the current set.

I believe, you must have declared questionNumber  as global variable, outside function block.

I've sorted it, thank you all for the help
